# viewing pdf as image flow - php

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a pdf file and I want to view them as image file (like in **google books** or **amazon book preview**). I hope there will be solution in some php libraries or javascript. I am expecting a similar solution. How can I make this possible??

Thanks in advance... `:)`

blasteralfred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and run it with GhostScript 
You can also have a look here: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=134543