# Need to create image from content of div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, prototype

I want to create a programme that can

1. take text input from user and adjust anywhere in specific div
2. change font, fontcolor and size as per user selection
3. upload image as background
4. save whole customization and send as email

with help of PHP/JavaScript 
Can anyone suggest how to do this.
Main issue is create image from user customization.
An existing programme to do this is also acceptable

I am programmer and working on php javascript magento

Comment: This is pretty complex. If you don't have much knowledge in PHP, JavaScript, CSS and HTML, you will find it extremely difficult to program by yourself. What is your question exactly? What do you already have?

Comment: i want like this http://www.beltbuckleshop.com/page/belt/PROD/photo/pboval click on Customize Belt Buckle. i have knowledge php javascript html etc and i create some element also but main issue is create image from content of div

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Reading your description, it doesn't sound like you really need a screencapture-like version of the content the user created, you just need an HTML embedded editor and a way for someone to upload an image as the background with a way to preview the result. You can send emails with backgrounds using CSS.

1. (Not sure what you mean, but I presume you can figure this one out)
2. Use TinyMCE for an editor: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/
3. Use jQuery AJAX file upload plugins (maybe http://www.uploadify.com/)
4. Submit the form (with the selected settings and edited html) to server and process as email

Try here for how to add an image to the background of an email:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3170/adding-background-images-to-your-email-in-two-simple-steps/

Comment: this WYSIWYG is good but its not much helpfully in my project i want move element anywhere in div and save image exalts looking in browser.

Comment: Well, I've heard of approached in which the server sends the data through a PDF process and then turns that into an image. Otherwise, I'd look into jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: can you tell me about pdf process if we create image then is it ok in over case. thanks for replies

Comment: That's a pretty complex chain. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php for what HTML to PDF options exist, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528951/viewing-pdf-as-image-flow-php for more PDF to image information.